# Better way select data from related entities into a list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is a representation of my DB

[image]

I need to create a list of all `Answers` but to include properties from the related tables, I.E,

```
Answer.ID
Response
QuestionText
CategortText
ProcessText 
etc....
```

I thought I could do

```
IList<Answer> result = db.Answers.ToList();
```

but this seems to create a massive list due to all the navigation properties.

Is there a simpler way? I thought about a view model but didn't fancy typing out 30+ properties....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit your data, the best way is to create new type like `NewAnswer`and then You can use casting based on combination of properties like"

```
IList<NewAnswer> result = db.Answers
                         .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                         {
                          Response= x.Response,
                          QuestionText= x.Question.QuestionText
                         }).ToList());
```